# Vue.js: can't orderBy in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've upgraded to Vue.js 2.0.5 and orderBy in a v-for seems to not be working anymore

```
<li v-for="c in rooms | orderBy 'last_iteraction'">
```

outputs

> - invalid expression: v-for="c in rooms | orderBy 'last_iteraction'"

anyone knows how to solve?

Comment: `last_iteraction` or `last_interaction`?

Comment: 'last_iteraction' in this case. Bu this not work with any attribute from a 'room' object.

Comment: see that [Docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-orderBy-Filter)

Comment: @haim770 this was a 'pre-built' filter from the previous Vue's release (1.x)

Comment: @ABDEL-RHMAN thanks, this worked.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

orderBy Filter is removed in vue.js v-2.

Quoted from vue.js docs

Instead of:

> `<p v-for="user in users | orderBy 'name'">{{ user.name }}</p>`

Use lodash’s orderBy (or possibly sortBy) in a computed property:

> `<p v-for="user in orderedUsers">{{ user.name }}</p>`

> ```
> computed: {
>   orderedUsers: function () {
>     return _.orderBy(this.users, 'name')
>   }
> }
> ```

Reference:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-orderBy-Filter

Comment: I spent some time searching for some info about orderBy in the v2 and didn't find this link. Thanks!

Comment: Do we need to load lodash library in order to use orderBy function?

Comment: Yes – you can install lodash in your project, and add this to your component: `import _ from 'lodash'`

Comment: No, you do not need lodash just to [sort an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: If you still want the lodash sorting without the full library, you can just use the [`lodash.orderby`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.orderby) [modularized](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Build-Differences/49298d1df3ed0ce0cf4c123b5b21efb5bd9e94cf) build.

Comment: However take notice, on the [Roadmap](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Roadmap/49298d1df3ed0ce0cf4c123b5b21efb5bd9e94cf#v500-2018) for v5.0.0 it is planned to _Discontinue [per method packages](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lodash-modularized) in favor of modular [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash)_

Comment: I downvoted because it doesn't solve a problem where you have v-for inside v-for and the "orderedUsers" is created on the fly

Comment: Khorshed - where would you place that 'computed' paragraph?

Comment: @SteveStaple It should go as a property of the vue instance. You can check the docs for computed property to learn more, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties

Comment: @KhorshedAlam - it does not work for me. I get this error: ReferenceError: _ is not defined. It does not appear to like the underscore?

Comment: What happens if we need to access a value based on some other instance, like using a v-for inside a Buefy `table-detail` slot? The value lays inside a `props.row` acessor.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use vue2 filters package.

1. First install it using npm.

> npm install vue2-filters

2. Then, add it in your component or globally.

> ```
> import Vue from 'vue'
> import Vue2Filters from 'vue2-filters'
>   
> Vue.use(Vue2Filters)
> ```

3. To use one of the predefined methods (such as limitBy, filterBy, find, or orderBy) in your component, you also need to add Vue2Filters.mixin to mixin list:

> ```
> import Vue2Filters from 'vue2-filters'
>
> export default {
>   ...
>   mixins: [Vue2Filters.mixin],
>   ...
> }
> ```

4. After that use it in the template

> ```
>  <li v-for="c in orderBy(rooms,'last_iteraction')">
> ```

There is a list of predefined filters.check it out.

**Reference:**

https://github.com/freearhey/vue2-filters