# Vue.js rewriting orderBy Filter in v-for

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, components

Since the orderBy Filter is removed in vue.js v-2 I want to now how one can rewrite this codepart:

```
<li class="day" v-for="day in days | orderBy 'unix' 1" v-bind:class="{ 'outside': day.outsideOfCurrentMonth, 'empty': day.events.length === 0 }">
```

I thought of writing

```
<li class="day" v-for="day in orderedDays"{{}}>
```

but I don't know what to write in the brackets and what to write in `orderBy()`:

```
computed: {
  orderedDays: function () {
    return _.orderBy()
  }
}
```

[Here](https://codeshare.io/GbMp3v) is the full component. 
Can someone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js: can't orderBy in v-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512585/vue-js-cant-orderby-in-v-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<li class="day" v-for="day in orderedDays">
```

```js
computed: {
  orderedDays: function () {
    return _.orderBy(this.days, ['unix'], ['asc'])
  }
}
```